# The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have a code to delete file in my folder, but in my line code, I want to delete two file together with different folder. But I always get an error "the process cannot access.... another process". May be you can correct my code and give me a solution. Thanks

1) I have a code to generate watermark when save file(.pdf):

```
public bool InsertWaterMark(string path)
    {
        bool valid = true; 
        string FileDestination = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Content/" + path;
        string FileOriginal = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Content/" + path.Replace("FileTemporary", "FileOriginal");
        System.IO.File.Copy(FileDestination, FileOriginal); 
        string watermarkText = "Controlled Copy";

        #region process
        PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(FileOriginal);//startFile
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileDestination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))//watermarkedFile
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fs))
            {
                int pageCount1 = reader1.NumberOfPages; 
                PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("WatermarkLayer", stamper.Writer);
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount1; i++)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = reader1.GetPageSize(i); 
                    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetUnderContent(i); 
                    cb.BeginLayer(layer);
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 80);
                    PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
                    gState.FillOpacity = 0.15f;
                    cb.SetGState(gState);
                    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
                    cb.BeginText();
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, watermarkText, rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, 45f);
                    cb.EndText(); 

                    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
                    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                    canvas.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                    PdfGState gStateFooter = new PdfGState();
                    gStateFooter.FillOpacity = 1f;
                    canvas.SetGState(gStateFooter);
                    canvas.BeginText();
                    canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                    canvas.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, '"' + "When printed, this documents are considered uncontrolled" + '"', 300.7f, 10.7f, 0);
                    canvas.EndText();
                    cb.EndLayer();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
       return valid;
    }
```

2) And this code i call when delete detail data from one page together.

```
    public ActionResult Delete(string parm)
    {
        TableEDIS data = db.TableEDISs.FirstOrDefault(e => e.detail_guid_edis == new Guid(parm));
        string fisikFile = data.upload_document;
        string fisikFileFormulir = data.upload_document_formulir;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fisikFile))
        {
            var relativePath = "~/Content/" + fisikFile;
            var absolutePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(relativePath);
            var absolutePathOriginal = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(relativePath.Replace("Temporary", "Original"));

            if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(absolutePath)))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(absolutePath);
            } 

            if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(absolutePathOriginal)))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(absolutePathOriginal);
            } 
        }
    }
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's nothing to do with trying to delete two files in one method, you're just trying to delete a file that is being used by some application.  Have you got the file open within your software?

Comment: Guess `File.Exists` is better choice than `Directory.Exists` in this case.

Comment: This is one of the most frequently incorrect error messages you'll encounter. In my experience, its far more likely that the "other process" is in fact your own process. Check that you're not leaving open/leaking any other objects that relate to these files, such as streams.

Comment: before the command to delete the file. in my controller file there are other processes like create watermark for pdf with itextsharp, pdfreader. does it affect? if yes for now what should i do?

Comment: You do not happen to have the pdf file open somewhere? Adobe reader puts a lock on its open pdf files.

Comment: ok, may be i must edit my question with complete my code. wait a minute.

Comment: Don't you need to close the PdfReader object reader1 in the InsertWaterMark method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My spidey senses tells me you need to call

```
reader1.Close();
```

Comment: it works, oh my god, i'm forgot to close this. hehehe... thank you very much

Comment: I'm working in a multi-threaded environment with Spring Batch, got this error and thought this was going to mean spending the next week of my life trying to solve it, but no, your spidey sense saved me today, wish I could upvote this 100 times

Comment: Glad iI could help